# cygwin shell in emacs /cmd.exe in windows

Tags: windows, emacs, cygwin

I am attempting to get python to run in a command shell in emacs. I have tried the standard M-x shell that comes with windows emacs and then type 'python' but python just hangs up (no output). I have also tried running other program shells such as bash.exe from cygwin with the same result. Any way to get a shell that can run other programs like python?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `M-x python-shell`?  This provides an interactive REPL for Python within Emacs.

Comment: That'll probably do it. There may be difficulties with this Python not being the system python and/or path'd from a different location than expected.